# Retrieving Only last years data with count - Carbon [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.3

I am making a counter to ONLY retrieve last years data, 2017. Only from January - December. My next function will be `subYears(1)` to get the previous years data.

Currently I have,

```
  $intake = Intake::where('confirmed', 1)
                      ->where('officiant_id', $this->id)
                       ->whereIn('weddingStartDateTime', Carbon::now()->format('Y') )
                      ->get();
```

(The get will be replaced with a `->count` I just wanted to display that for testing purposes.

How can I get only last years data? Has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's query builder has a [`whereYear()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) function:

```
$intake = Intake::where('confirmed', 1)
        ->where('officiant_id', $this->id)
        ->whereYear('weddingStartDateTime', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `whereBetween()`

e.g. `Intake::whereBetween('weddingStartDateTime',[$date1,$date2]);`

Comment: I'm not a fan of this approach. The `whereYear()` method was made specifically for these scenarios.

Comment: Yeah it's ideal for this situation, didn't know about it until now. Thanks!